# What is the folded size of a sectional map?

Tags: usa, aeronautical-charts

Bending aluminum for a map box, and am curious as to the folded dimension of a sectional chart. My present resources use moving maps on EFIS and iPad, but I would like to carry standard paper charts.

Comment: Your best bed is to get an actual chart which runs for less than $10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One seller's link on Amazon claimed 10" x 5", but when I measured an old one (only one I have handy), it was between 10.25" and 10.5" long by 5" wide. So I'd recommend using the latter value, knowing that the chart will probably be a hair under 10.5" long and so you have room for error (or a badly refolded chart).

Comment: A Van's map box kit has a 12" depth, my application only allows 11.5". The actual measurement provides positive verification, thanks.